# Как получить информацию о компании из GoogleMaps по названию или адресу?

Tags: google-maps-api, парсер, iframe, google-maps

Есть допустим адрес (я его сократил) https://goo.gl/MQRdob хочу из него встроить на сайт инфу которая в левом сайдбаре.

Как лучше сделать, при условии, что мне надо добавить описание всех онкоцентров СНГ? Адреса или названия найду.

Может ifame, парсить, или может у гугла есть какието инструменты о которых я не знаю?

Comment: Places Library Вам не подойдет? (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)